# FileInputStream for a raw file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, inputstream, fileinputstream

I have a raw file in `res/raw` named "`pack.dat`".

I can open an `InputStream` with the following code:

```
    InputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pack);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String nextLine;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (j == 5) {
                j = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is working, I can read from that file.

But unfortunately I need a `FileInputStream`. When I do this:

```
    FileInputStream fs = null;
    Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + 
                     context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.pack);
    File file = new File(url.toString());
    try {
        fs = new FileInputStream(file);
        fs.getChannel().position(0);
        fs.read(bDatensatz, 0, indexlaenge);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get a "`file not found`" at

```
fs = new FileInputStream(file);
```

`context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pack)` in the first example returns an `InputStream`.

What can I use to get a `FileInputStream` instead?

Answer (score 2):

copied  from another thread! may be this should help you

```
FileInputStream fis;
fis = openFileInput("test.txt");
StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int n  = 0;

while ((n = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
{ 
  fileContent.append(new String(buffer, 0, n)); 
}
```

Comment: this is only working if I have a String with the filename. But my file is in res/raw.  With url.toString I get something like "android.resource://com.foo.myprogram/2131099648". 

How can I address this file?

Comment: I think there is a  problem  with url.toString() method.There, you are trying to parse `R.raw.pack`  (Resource ID) into string which is not what  you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

> But unfortunately I need a FileInputStream

Why?

> I get a "file not found" at fs = new FileInputStream(file);

That is because you are trying to open something that is not a file.

> What can I use to get a FileInputStream instead?

You would need to copy the resource to a local file (e.g., using `openFileOutput()` and Java I/O). Then, you can open the local file (e.g., using `openFileInput()`) and get a `FileInputStream`.

Or, just use the `InputStream`, fixing whatever code that you are using that is expecting a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: 1. I need to set the file position for random read.

2. The file "res/raw/pack.dat" is available. In my second example you can see how I prepare the file.

3. Would you like to say it's impossible to read a raw file with a FileInputStream?

The file is 15 MB in size and I want to avoid to copy it to a local file, especially not to the sdcard.

Comment: @thpitsch: "The file "res/raw/pack.dat" is available" -- on your development machine. It is not a file on Android. "Would you like to say it's impossible to read a raw file with a FileInputStream?" -- correct.

Comment: The data are in the resources and goes with the apk to the device. If it is not a file, how can I make a copy to getMainActivity().getFilesDir()?

Comment: @thpitsch: "If it is not a file, how can I make a copy to getMainActivity().getFilesDir()?" -- use your first code snippet to get an `InputStream` on the raw resource. Then, get a `FileOutputStream` on your desired file (e.g., `new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(), "thing.txt"))`). Then, use Java I/O to copy the data from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`, flushing and closing the `FileOutputStream` when you are done. There are plenty of code snippets around showing how to copy data from one stream to another in Java.

Comment: Thank you! After days of trying to build up a FileInputStream on a raw resource, now I copy that file at the very first start to the app's FilesDir and can work with a FileInputStream afterwards as desired.